# Inline callback function within a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function containing a callback that I want to optionally relay back to the original function call when it is complete... If that makes sense.

e.g.:

```
const UI = {
    update : function(var1) {
        $(var1).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, "linear", function() {
                // Callback 1: Do stuff
        });
    }
}
```

What I want is to have the following:

```
UI.update("whatever", function() {
   // Callback 2: Do more stuff after Callback 1 is complete
});
```

Is it possible to do it inline like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, certainly — just declare a parameter for the callback, and then if `update` doesn't have to do anything when the animation is finished, just pass the callback to `animate` directly:

```
const UI = {
    update : function(var1, callback) {
// -------------------------^
        $(var1).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, "linear", callback); // ***
    }
};
```

If `update` needs to do more work before calling the callback, just call the callback from within the `animate` callback:

```
const UI = {
    update : function(var1, callback) {
    // ---------------------^
        $(var1).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, "linear", function() {
            // ...work `update` does here...
            // Call the callback:
            if (callback) {                                           // ***
                callback(/*...perhaps some arguments here...*/);      // ***
            }                                                         // ***
        });
    }
}
```

It's not a problem that the call to `callback` won't be until after `update` has returned. The `animate` callback is a *closure*¹<sup>,</sup>² over `var1` and `callback` *(more accurately, over the lexical environment they exist within)*, so they'll remain accessible after `update` returns.

You may be happy with just the "truthy" check shown above. Other times, people are more rigorous, e.g.:

```
if (typeof callback === "function") {
```

*(Many years ago, in web browsers some host-provided functions had `"object"` rather than `"function"` for their `typeof`, but all vaguely-modern browsers ensure it's `"function"` now.)*

---

For more about closures:

¹ [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) on my anemic little blog (some outdated terminology, but...)

² [Canonical Stack Overflow question about closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you gents. @T.J.Crowder I assume any work `update` needs to do should happen before the `.animate` call anyway (unless of course it needs to be done after the animation)?

Comment: @Microsis - It depends on what the work is, but probably, yeah. :-)